# Infinite line is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, normed-spaces

I have been reading the book "Elements of the functional analisys", by Kolmogorov and Fomin. At the chapter of Normed Linear Spaces, page 73 to be precise, the author makes the following definitions:

A linear mainfold $L$ in a normed linear space $\mathbb{R}$ is any set of elements satisfying the following condition: if $x,y$ belong to $L$, then for any two arbitary numbers $a$ and $b$,  $a\cdot x + b\cdot y$ does also belong to $L$.

A subspace of a space $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed linear mainfold in $\mathbb{R}$.

After defining linear mainfold and subspace the author proposes the reading to prove that given any euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, evey linear mainfold is a subspace; i.e every linear mainfold is closed.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance upon this proof.( Especially if you could first help me prove that, since any straight line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear mainfold, that every straight line is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in the sense that it contains its limit points)

Comment: It might help to correct that to "Every closed line _through the origin_ in $\Bbb R^n$", otherwise it isn't closed under addition and scalar multiplication. (If the line doesn't contain the origin, then for any $x$ that is on the line, $x + x$ isn't.)

Comment: Thank you Arthur I will clarify that. However, by closed I meant that the straight line contained its limit points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** A straight line passing through origin is **one** dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

**Every finite-dimensional subspace of a normed space is
closed and complete.**

A straight line through the points $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is subset $L=\{a(1-t)+bt:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$

$L$ is closed as it contains all its limit points.

Let $x_n\in L\ni x_n\to x$

enough to show $x\in L$

$x_n= a(1-t_n)+bt_n\in L$, as $a(1-t)+bt$ is continuous so $a(1-t_n)+bt_n\to a(1-k)+bk=x$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$, so $x\in L$ too. Done!

In other way,  a straight line $\{ax+by+c=0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ say, is just inverse image of $\{0\}$ under continuous map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\to ax+by+c$

Can you generalize for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is very useful to proving that a straight line is closed. Nevertheless I was looking forward to proving this without using that the straight line is a subspace, since my objective is to show that every  linear mainfold is a subspace by showing first that it is closed.

Comment: Very nice. Given an n dimensional linear mainfold L. The continuity of the mapping f(a) = Ax where a belongs to R^m and A=(v1|v2|..|vm) is a nxm matrix and each vi belongs to R^n implies that the inverse image of {0} (which is the desired linear mainfold) is closed and therefore a subspace.( i am still reviewing this)